# How to Pass Details Model from Controller to View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, razor

I am accessing Data in Controller using a WCF Service.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DataRerieveClient _proxy = new DataRerieveClient();
            var orderDetails = _proxy.GetProductDetails(null);
            return View();
        }
```

Now how to pass the `orderdetails` from Controller to view and how to access them in View.

**Edit:**

I have a Model :

```
 public class OrderDetails
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public int quanity { get; set; }
        public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    }
```

and  `_proxy.GetProductDetails(null)` returns `List<ServiceType.OrderDetails>`

1. Do I need a Local Model at all in this scenario?
2. How do I display the List values in a table in my view?

**Edit2:**

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.Map(ServiceOrders.OrderDetails, NorthWindMVCWCF.Models.OrderDetails);
        }
    }
```

Now getting the Error

> 'NorthWindMVCWCF.ServiceOrders.OrderDetails' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context
>   'NorthWindMVCWCF.Models.OrderDetails' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: I updated my answer. I think you can get a good idea out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to create view models, I would do it as follows:

**Create View Models**

```
public class OrderDetailViewModel
{
  public int OrderId { get; set; }
  public int ProductId { get; set; }
  public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
  public int Quanity { get; set; }
  public decimal Discount { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetailsViewModel
{
  public OrderDetailsViewModel()
  {
      OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetailsViewModel>();
  }

  public List<OrderDetailsViewModel> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

**Manual projection**

You could create an `OrderDetails` view model and project an instance manually as follows:

```
var orderDetailsViewModel = new OrderDetailsViewModel();
foreach(var orderdetail in orderDetails)
{
 orderDetailsViewModel.Add(new OrderDetailsViewModel { OrderId = orderDetail.OrderId, ProductId = orderDetail.ProductId, UnitPrice = orderDetail.UnitPrice, Quanity = orderDetail.quantity, Discount = orderDetail.Discount });
}
```

**AutoMapper alternative projection**

Install AutoMapper, run the following from the package manager console:

```
Install-Package AutoMapper
```

Create an `AutoMapperConfig.cs` in the `App_Start` folder with the mappings, similar to below:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
  public static void Configure()
  {
    Mapper.CreateMap<OrderDetails, OrderDetailViewModel>();
  }
}
```

In your global asax call the configure method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   ...
   AutoMapperConfig.Configure();
   ...
}
```

Then map in your controller:

```
var orderDetailsViewModel = new OrderDetailsViewModel();
orderDetailsViewModel.OrderDetails = Mapper.Map<List<OrderDetails>, List<OrderDetailsViewModel>>(orderDetails);
```

I prefer to use the AutoMapper approach as the mapping is defined globally and can be reused within your app.

**Returning your view model**

Your view model would then be passed back as follows:

```
        return View(orderDetailsViewModel);
```

**Razor output**

You access it in your view by adding a model reference at the top:

```
@model OrderDetailsViewModel
```

Then output the properties as follows, I've only included `OrderId` but you can just add the fields the same way:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>OrderId</th>
</tr>
@foreach(var orderDetail in Model.OrderDetails)
{
  <tr>
    <td>@orderDetail.OrderId</td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Made some Clarifications in edit of my question , could you please have a look

Comment: Ok, updated the question to be more specific for you. :)

Comment: AutoMapper Seems intresting , in which class should I declare the Mapping , scince there FilterConfig.cs, RouteConfig.cs and WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: So Automapper is trying to map the Service type to Model Type. But why  am I getting the error then

Comment: In your configure you need to call CreateMap, this is where your mapping is defined. i.e. Mapper.CreateMap<NorthWindMVCWCF.Models.OrderDetails, ServiceOrders.OrderDetails>; You can configure specific mapping there, for instance there might be certain fields you need to ignore etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47859/discussion-between-simsons-and-hutchonoid)

Answer (score 1):

You have create ViewModel for that.

For example in your model folder create a class:

```
public class MyViewModel // Whatever name you want to give
{
     //My fields which I want to pass to View
     publis string Field1{get;set;}
     etc
     etc
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
      DataRerieveClient _proxy = new DataRerieveClient();
      var orderDetails = _proxy.GetProductDetails(null);

      List<MyViewModel> viewModelList = new List<MyViewModel>();

      foreach(var orderDetail in orderDetails)
      {
           MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel(); //Create an object of your ViewModel
           viewModel.Field1 = orderDetails.Field1; //set all feilds like that      
           viewModelList.Add(viewModel); 
      }   
      return View(viewModelList); // Pass View Model to View
}
```

**Note: You have to create View for your ViewModel**
Like

```
@model `List<MyViewModel>`
```

then use this ViewModel to access properties.

To know more about what is ViewModel, refer to the link below:

http://sampathloku.blogspot.ae/2012/10/how-to-use-viewmodel-with-aspnet-mvc.html

Answer (score 0):

in the Controller class write :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   DataRerieveClient _proxy = new DataRerieveClient();
   var orderDetails = _proxy.GetProductDetails(null);
   return View(orderDetails);
}
```

i assume your project name is MvcApplication2 and your class name is in Model Folder. so add follow code in top of View (sample.cshtml) :

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.OrderDetail
```

ok , you can use this code to access properties of DataRecieveClient :

```
<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.F1)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.F1)
</div>
```

Sorry for poor english.!